# Change bg color when radio btn is selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms

I need to change the bg color of a div containing a radio button when the user slects the button. I am using jquery - so its seems like there should be some simple way to accomplish this. I have my html setup something like this:

```
<div class="sales_box">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="radio_cell"><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<div class="sales_box">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="radio_cell"><input type="radio"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just handle the change event of the radio button and then use the [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) method of jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
       $(this).closest('div').css('background-color', 'red');
    });
});
```

And as redsquare has said, you shouldn't really set inline css. You should use the [toggleclass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) function. I just used the css function as an example.

Comment: this will change the td background

Comment: @redsquare - No need for the downvote, give me change to correct it first.

Comment: Yeah, I'd like to change the div background color. Is there a way to use this method and target the div?

Comment: also I would use toggleClass rather than set inline css

Comment: @redsquare - sorry, just assumed as the downvote happened at the same minute you posted that it was you. Anyway, all corrected and working now.

Comment: @redsquare - Forgot I had the link on SO. Removed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 $(function() {
        $(".radio_cell input[type=radio]").bind("click", function() {
            $(this).parents('div:first').css("background-color", "Blue");
        });
    });
```

Comment: closest is better here, this way gets all parents then filters

Answer (score 0):

I would use the toggleClass rather than setting inline css.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
       $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Comment: I just added a follow up to this regarding the deselect behavior:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078781/change-bg-on-radio-deselect