# Change bg on radio deselect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, forms

This is just an add on to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078714/change-bg-color-when-radio-btn-is-selected). Once I deselect the radio button I need to return the background color to its original state. So the solution we came up with is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input:radio').change(function(){
        $(this).closest('div').toggleClass('highlight');
    });
});
```

Now I need to remove the highlight class when the radio button is deselected - any ideas?

Comment: I think you actually want checkboxes, since you are using only one radio button per section and they are not grouped. You cannot deselect one radio

Comment: otherwise group the radios by giving them all the same name attribute

Comment: Sorry - I have multiple radios, I simplified the HTML I posted earlier and removed the form tags. I have also given them the same name attributes so they do unselect when the user clicks a different radio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, group your radios using the name attribute and the following js should work

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/emaxa/3)

```
 $('input:radio').change(function(){
        $('div.highlight').removeClass('highlight');
        $(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, I agree with redsquare, you can see this my code demo on jsfiddle, with the div onclick select the radio.

```
$('table div').click(function() {
      $(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
      $('div.highlight_row').removeClass('highlight');
      $(this).closest('div').addClass('highlight');
});
```

you can see the full code here, but the change is on tr class, not the div class :

[JsFiddle Code Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/Lk8c1hyc/)